# Heston Discretization dt

Tags: option-pricing, monte-carlo, heston

I’m trying to figure out the discretization of the Heston model. In the choice of `dt`, I have seen several ways that people specify this number. Would it not just be `1/n` where `n` is the number time steps? And the paper mentions that the wiener processes should be normally distributed with variance `dt`, but I often don’t see that mentioned and implementations seem to leave that out a lot. If using `dt = 0.04`, that sounds like a very small variance. Is that correct?

Comment: The size of a time step $dt$ should be as a big as possible (to reduce computational burden) but as small as possible (to reduce the scheme-dependent discrétisation bias). The variance of the increment of a Brownian driver is indeed $dt$ over that interval. But the instantaneous variance of $S_t$ (resp. $v_t$) over $dt$ is given by $v_t dt$ (resp. $\sigma \sqrr{v_t}$)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out some things that might be helpful.

> I’m trying to figure out the discretization of the Heston model. In the choice of `dt` ...

There exists many discretization schemes that could be implemented to simulate a system of stochastic differential equations (SDEs), such as the Heston model. One of them is the EulerMaruyama scheme, which has a $\frac{1}{2}$ strong order or $1$ weak order of convergence. I believe you are referring to this particular scheme.

The Heston model is given by:

\begin{aligned}
  dS(t) &= r \cdot S(t) \cdot dt + \sqrt{v(t)} \cdot S(t) \cdot dW(t), \\
  dv(t) &= \kappa \cdot \left( \theta - v(t) \right) \cdot dt + \sqrt{v(t)} \cdot dZ(t)
\end{aligned}

with:

\begin{aligned}
  S(0) &= S_0, \\
  v(0) &= v_0, \\
  \langle dW(t), dZ(t) \rangle &= \rho \cdot dt.
\end{aligned}

It is important to note that this system of SDEs has actually non-diagonal noise, since diffusion of the stock price dynamics has a non-null derivative with respect to the variance $v(t)$. This has an important impact in which discretization schemes can be applied. Fortunately, the EulerMaruyama is still aplicable in systems with non-diagonal noise. On the contrary, the EulerMaruyama may need more simulation paths and smaller $dt$ than other schemes in order to achieve convergence when pricing an option. I would recommend reading "Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differential Equations" from Kloeden and Platen to get more insight about the discretization schemes for SDEs.

> Would it not just be `1/n` where `n` is the number time steps?

Yes, of course: if `n` is the number of steps per year, you can either specify `n` and compute `dt` or specify `dt` and compute `n`. The problem is different: which `n` or `dt` should I select for my simulation?

In my opinion, the best way to figure out this is by conducting an analysis of the following aspects:

1. For a System of SDEs with analytical solution, which $dt$ and $N$ (number of trajectories or paths) should I use in order to achieve convergence.
2. You can compute the price of a derivative numerically (varying $dt$ and $N$) and analytically and check when you achieve convergence (the frontier of convergence).
3. Check the cost-benefit of increasing trials, diminishing the time step and their consequences on the computational time.

Many other tests can be included, these are just a couple of them. Also, there are discretization schemes that use adaptive time steps! You can think about them by making a comparison with ODE solvers with adaptive time steps.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The problem that I am seeing mostly is that the choice of `dt` affects where the paths converge. Convergence isn't that big of an issue because I can always add more paths. But what choice of `dt` would give a more accurate convergence? It seems that depending on the way you look at it, `dt` could be the total number of steps or the number of steps annually. Say that I have 365 steps per year and the simulation is over 2 years, should `dt` equal $\frac{1}{365}$ or $\frac{1}{730}$?